# Are there plans to allow users to see what questions they've upvoted and also to see their statistics regarding their activity?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For example, I'd love to see how many questions I've browsed/ upvoted in the last 24 hours or last week, in addition to keeping track of which questions I've visited (like a log of what you've learnt.)

I know there's a Site Analytics dashboard that opens up when you get 25k rep, but I guess what I'm asking for is a user Analytics dashboard and if there's something in the works regarding that.

Additionally, I'm resorting to "favoriting" questions currently to keep track of the ones I want to revisit, even if they aren't my "favorites". Was this meantto be used as a bookmarking feature? Because you sometimes end up starring questions that you simply want to revisit to answer - not ideal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes - we track views in aggregate, and in theory we could pull individual views from the logs & store 'em somewhere... But it'd be a lot of data. Also, some folks would probably find it a bit creepy. Not ruling it out, but probably not soon.

Comment: Ah. I see your point. But yeah, tracking it by upvoting will probably work for now.

Comment: Site Analytics dashboard - didn't know about that. Are there some screenshots somewhere?